# Polygons within Polygons

Tags: qgis, vector, query

I am using QGIS V3.30

I have  a set of polygons, being farm boundaries. I have another set of building polygons comprising various features within the farms.

I would like to get a table listing all building polygons with the farm  that they fall in as an attribute. This will allow me to determine  total buildings per farm as well as total building area by farm.

I have tried the Intersection tool but it only returns a single feature.

Comment: This is unclear: Do you want to know, how much space buildings take up within each farm, and how many buildings there are? Or do you want to know, which farm each building is situated in?

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood you correctly then here is a GIF showing you how I would do this using the Join attributes by Location tool:

[image]

Here is a screenshot as the GIF isn't the clearest:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the 'Join attributes by location' function will work for you.

Comment: Both the 'Join by Attributes' & 'Intersection' tools worked for this query. However, they both create  a new layer.

I wish to add an attribute from the Overlay layer into the existing Input layer where my  features  are.

Is there an option to do this?